# Using Minim library in Java. Couldn't get the helper class working

Tags: java, processing, fft, audio-processing, minim

I'm using the Minim 2.2.0 library with JAVA.  The library requires us to define a helper class defining two methods and pass an object of this class to the Minim constructor. I wrote the MinimHelper class as follows.

```
public class MinimHelper {
    String sketchPath( String fileName ) {
        return "C:\\Users\\Martin\\Downloads\\"+fileName;
    }

    InputStream createInput(String fileName) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try{
            is = new FileInputStream(sketchPath(fileName));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return is;
    }
}
```

And I wrote my main as follows

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AudioPlayer player;
        Minim minim = new Minim (new MinimHelper());
        player = minim.loadFile("Butterfly.mp3");
        player.play();
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error in the console.

```
==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Couldn't find a sketchPath method on the file loading object provided!
==== File recording will be disabled.

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Couldn't find a createInput method in the file loading object provided!
==== File loading will be disabled.

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Error invoking createInput on the file loader object: null

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ddf.minim.javasound.JSMinim.getAudioRecordingStream(Unknown Source)
    at ddf.minim.Minim.loadFile(Unknown Source)
    at ddf.minim.Minim.loadFile(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Please tell me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where exactly is the `Butterfly.mp3` file located?

Comment: you have [multiple questions in a single question, only ask one question per question](https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow%20one%20question%20per%20question&rct=j), one is a duplicate the others are probably answered by @KevinWorkman with the visibility modifiers.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, and [Processing isn't Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java). This NPE isn't caused by the same thing as the canonical Java NPE question (or, at the very least, it's caused by a more complicated issue that deserve its own question). I'm voting to reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `sketchPath()` and `createInput()` functions need to be `public` for Minim to be able to find them.

Going through [the source](https://github.com/ddf/Minim/blob/master/src/ddf/minim/javasound/JSMinim.java), Minim eventually calls `Class.getMethod()` to get the functions you've defined. From [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified **public** member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.

**If that's not the problem:** Make sure the `Butterfly.mp3` file is where you're telling it to look.

Does `C:\\Users\\Martin\\Downloads\\Butterfly.mp3` exist? Does it have the correct permissions?

For more information, you might try adding print statements inside your `MinimHelper` class. Are the functions being called? What are the values being passed to it?

Comment: Making the sketchPath() and createInput() as public resolved the issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MartinBorugadda No problem. I see why you were confused, the documentation doesn't say anything about making them public. Happy coding!